# Classe polinômio - list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes

Salve pessoal, estou aprendendo classes em python e criei uma para aplicação com polinômios, porém não estou conseguindo somar dois polinômios distintos, sempre aparece o seguinte erro:

> File "/home/leticia/Documentos/python/Poo/polinomio.py", line 30, in
>   
>       p3 = p1 + p2   File "/home/leticia/Documentos/python/Poo/polinomio.py", line 19, in
>   **add**
>       soma.termos[i] = self.termos[i] + other[i] IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Nessas tentativas de solucionar, acrescentei até um atributo para passar a dimensão do vetor, mas continuo na mesma, onde estou errando?

```
class Polinomio:

    def __init__ (self, termos = None, n = 0):
        self.termos = termos or []
        self.n = [0] * n

    def __len__ (self):
        return len(self.termos)

    def __setitem__ (self, i, x):
        self.termos[i] = x

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.termos[i] 

    def __add__ (self, other):
        soma = Polinomio(n = self.termos.__len__())
        for i in range(self.termos.__len__()):
            soma.termos[i] = self.termos[i] + other[i]
        return soma

    def print (self):
        print(self.termos)


p1 = Polinomio([1, 2, 3])
p2 = Polinomio([1, 2, 3])
p2.print()
p3 = Polinomio()
p3 = p1 + p2
```

Comment: No método `init` tente por `self.termos = termos or [0]*n`

Comment: Rodou obrigado, se quiser responder a questão para que eu possa marcar como resolvida

Comment: Vc esta usando os "metodos mágicos", na minha opinião faltou um bem iportante, por exemplo, ao invés de fazer `p2.print()` faça `print(p2)` ou `print(p3)` e veja o que acontece. O desejável (ou a convenção) seria que acontecesse o mesmo que acontece qdo vc chama o método `print`, ou seja, apresentasse os termos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[TL;DR]](https://repl.it/KaiI/5)

Tente assim:

```
class Polinomio:

    def __init__ (self, termos = None, n = 0):
        self.termos = termos or []
        self.n = [0] * n

    def __len__ (self):
        return len(self.termos)

    def __setitem__ (self, i, x):
        self.termos[i] = x

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.termos[i] 

    def __add__ (self, other):            
        return [x + y for x, y in zip(self.termos, other.termos)]

    def print (self):
        print(self.termos)
```

Testando:

```
p1 = Polinomio([1, 2, 3])
p2 = Polinomio([4, 5, 6])
print ('Termos de p1: ', p1.termos)
print ('Termos de p2: ', p2.termos)
print ('Soma de p1+p2: ', p1+p2)

Termos de p1:  [1, 2, 3]
Termos de p2:  [4, 5, 6]
Soma de p1+p2:  [5, 7, 9]
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/KaiI/5)

Comment: Só faltou o método `add` tornar um polinômio também. E dessa forma o `n` é desnecessário, certo?

Comment: Para falar a verdade só prestei atenção no erro que ele cometeu, nem analisei o problema como um todo. :-)

Comment: Sim, imaginei. Até porque utilizando o `zip` haverá o problema de somar polinômios de ordem distintas.

Comment: Verdade! Mas se ele tiver iniciando acho que ja ajuda (a lógica do problema fica a cargo dele, eheheh), as vezes fico pasmo como os iniciantes não conseguem intrepretar as mensagens de erros.